# Retrieve Firebase database values without 'true'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

This is how I insert values to my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child("Bus").child(driverFoundId).child("Students").child(userId);
                    driverRef.setValue(true);
```

And this is how I get values from the database:

```
driverId= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    assignedStudentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child("Bus").child(driverId).child("Students");
    assignedStudentListener =assignedStudentRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot ) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    
                    studentId = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                    
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                    studentId = map.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(DriverMapAct.this," "+studentId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getAssignedStudentPickupLocation();

                }
            }
    }
```

Because I previously gave setValue (true) to add values ​​to the database.  How to remove true when retrieving data?

Answer (score 0):

If the following line of code works fine to add data:

```
driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("User")
                .child("Bus")
                .child(driverFoundId)
                .child("Students")
                .child(userId);
                driverRef.setValue(true);
```

To remove the exact same value, please use [DatabaseReference#removeValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#removeValue()) method:

```
driverRef.removeValue();
```

Please note that is also an asynchronous operation. So you might consider attaching a listener to see if something goes wrong.

Comment: Hey Bhathisha. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?